# Can't rotate in pdftk

Tags: shell, pdf, pdftk

I am following the online instructions and trying to rotate **all pages** of a PDFs **90 degrees clockwise** like so

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1E output out.pdf
```

But then I get the following error

```
Error: Unexpected text in page range end, here: 
   1
   Exiting.
   Acceptable keywords, for example: "even" or "odd".
   To rotate pages, use: "north" "south" "east"
       "west" "left" "right" or "down"
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

I can't imagine what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compass direction should be given in full (`EAST` rather than `E`).

To rotate the first page:

```
pdftk t/helloworld.pdf cat 1EAST output out.pdf
```

To rotate all pages (page range `1-end`):

```
pdftk t/helloworld.pdf cat 1-endEAST output out.pdf
```